# How to update ng-model for datepicker if it's not a date object?

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-4

The ng-model is not updating the value when the value is not a date object. So for example, when I fill 2 in the input. The value is not updating and goes back to the previous valid value.

Tried to add ng-change based on the ng-model and turn this to a string. But didn't found a solution for this problem.

```
<input 
    type="text"
    ng-model="$ctrl.dateEntry"
    ng-blur="$ctrl.updateDate()"
/>
```

```
$onInit() {
    this.datePicker = this.elmnt.children[0];

    // Set value
    if (this.datePicker.values.length) {
        this.dateEntry = new Date(this.datePicker.values[0].split('-').reverse().join('-'));
    } else {
        this.dateEntry = null;
    }
}


updateDate() {
    if (this.dateEntry) {
        const date = this.dateEntry.getDate();
        // set month. getMonth gives a single zero based number. Needs to be increased by 1 and a zero needs to be added in front if it's a single digit.
        const month = ('0' + (this.dateEntry.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
        const year = this.dateEntry.getFullYear();

        this.elmnt.children[0].values[0] = `${date}-${month}-${year}`;
    }
}
```

Currently I get as default value the date, but when I change the value to an invalid value, like '22'. Ng model is not updating.

How to make it possible to update the ng model even if there is no valid value/date?

Comment: What datepicker are you using? Why would you want a non date value in a datepicker? That doesn't make sense. I'm pretty sure the datepicker probably has a built in requirement that the value is a valid date or it returns the last valid date.

Comment: bootstrap datepicker, because it is an optional value and I want to give the users the possibility to clear the field.